# Scriptella and &AMP; in the etl.xml

Tags: xml, dtd, scriptella

I use ampersand sign in the `<query>` value, so I encode it as `&amp;` but getting

```
5/04/2012 10:07:03 AM <WARNING> XML configuration warning in file:.../etl.xml(26:169): The entity "AMP" was referenced, but not declared.
```

The solution could be to create own DTD and define entity there. But the issue is that I use DTD from scriptella:

```
<!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
```

Any solution other than download, add entity and host locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `&#38;` instead of `&amp;`.

Alternatively, you should be able to add the declaration for amp to the internal subset:

```
<!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd" [
<!ENTITY amp "&#38;">
]>
```

Comment: Yep, both solutions worked. As well as changing `&AMP;` case to lower :-S thanks

Comment: @zerkms - Ahh...I see AMP in uppercase in the title, but in the question it was lowercase. I'm glad you got it figured out. :-)

Comment: Yep, I accidentally uppercased it when performed some changes to the query :-S